# Is there a way to read/write directly from/to the can-bus in android automotive?

Tags: android, can-bus, android-automotive

Assume I have a vehicle containing a screen that is connected to the vehicles can-bus and that the screen is using the android automotive OS. Disregard Google play store. Is it possible to create a third party app for android automotive that can read and send can-packets directly to the can-bus? The purpose is controlling physical third party addons connected to the can-bus, not to access functions already used by the vehicle like accelleration, engine-state and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct access to can-bus is not possible. Android Automotive uses [Vehicle HAL](https://source.android.com/docs/devices/automotive/security/vehicle_system_isolation#vehicle-hal) - Vehicle HAL is a lower layer that interacts with the vehicle, communicating with in-vehicle networks and other vehicular hardware.

Also, access to VHAL is restricted to system application.

Copied from s.a.c document

> The vehicle HAL is the only component in Android Automotive connected
> to the IVI system, either via direct Application
> Processor/MicroController connection or gated through a VMCU. Access
> to the Vehicle HAL should be restricted to system applications using
> SELinux rules and proper permissions on kernel interfaces.

PTAL https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/VehiclePropertyIds for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

While that last answer may be correct, I am not sure it's entirely accurate. My android radio uses a Can Bus adapter to control my climate and a few other things. That also does not mean it is playing by the rules, more so considering the radio origin.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35614682)