# Android Application, Need to receive the data from Microcontroller

Tags: android, microcontroller, android-automotive

I am working in Cluster Application, where team are sending the data through CAN to Microcontroller installed in my android board, from microcontroller it is transferring to Processor through UART. I am totally new about these things. My concern is how to receive the data from Processor to show in Application. **Is there any library for this**?
Thank You.

Comment: Anything that low-level should be documented by the ODM/board manufacturer/hardware integration team/custom ROM team. Perhaps a part of the [Vehicle Hardware Abstraction Layer](https://source.android.com/docs/automotive/vhal).

Comment: Thanks for confirmation, really it is very useful for me, No I am clear that the data to transferring to Processor, and LCD is connected through Processor, Now I have concern to get data from Processor through UART. Please help me out on this.
Thanks.

Comment: A UART pin on one board can be different in another manufacturer board. Only you or those who tasked you with this problem will know those details. [Is there a way to read/write directly from/to the can-bus in android automotive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75211234/295004) Perhaps this is useful but I don't know your hardware environment: http://openxcplatform.com/vehicle-interface/concepts.html

Comment: Is there any code change is required from AOSP side?